# How to feed data table from xml file received from Web API?

Tags: ado.net, asp.net-core-webapi

My Web API returns a string looking like XML file below. I put all rows ending with  \r\n to new line for readability.

```html
{"DataTable.RemotingVersion":{"major":2,"minor":0,"build":-1,"revision":-1,"majorRevision":-1,"minorRevision":-1},"XmlSchema":" <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>\r\n
<xs:schema xmlns=\"\" xmlns:xs=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:msdata=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata\">\r\n  
<xs:element name=\"Test\">\r\n    
<xs:complexType>\r\n      
<xs:sequence>\r\n        
<xs:element name=\"Col1\" type=\"xs:string\" msdata:targetNamespace=\"\" minOccurs=\"0\" />\r\n        
<xs:element name=\"Col2\" type=\"xs:string\" msdata:targetNamespace=\"\" minOccurs=\"0\" />\r\n      
</xs:sequence>\r\n    
</xs:complexType>\r\n  
</xs:element>\r\n  
<xs:element name=\"tmpDataSet\" msdata:IsDataSet=\"true\" msdata:MainDataTable=\"Test\" msdata:UseCurrentLocale=\"true\">\r\n    
<xs:complexType>\r\n      
<xs:choice minOccurs=\"0\" maxOccurs=\"unbounded\" />\r\n    
</xs:complexType>\r\n  
</xs:element>\r\n
</xs:schema>","XmlDiffGram":"<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata\" xmlns:diffgr=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1\">\r\n  
<tmpDataSet>\r\n    
<Test diffgr:id=\"Test1\" msdata:rowOrder=\"0\">\r\n      
<Col1>Column 1 value</Col1>\r\n      
<Col2>Column 2 value</Col2>\r\n    
</Test>\r\n  
</tmpDataSet>\r\n
</diffgr:diffgram>"}
```

I wonder how I can feed this string to a datatable? I tried to feed the table like this

```
System.Data.DataTable dt =  new System.Data.DataTable();
byte[] byteArray  =Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(<above string returned by Web API>);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream( byteArray );
dt.ReadXml(stream);
```

However, the code failed with exception
`System.Xml.XmlException: 'Data at the root level is invalid, position 1`

Comment: To clarify, my Web API is a .Net Core 2.2 Web API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Actually, your WebAPI didn't respond with a valid `XML` payload but return a `JSON` instead :

   ```
   {  
       "DataTable.RemotingVersion": {...},
       "XmlSchema":"... xml schema string ...",
       "XmlDiffGram": " ... xml data string ..."
   }
   ```

   So you can't read the whole string by `dt.ReadXml(stream);`
2. Also note that the xml string begins with an empty string. It's better to invoke `.Trim()` before reading the XML string.

**A working demo:**

Let's create two helper methods that read the schema & data parts into `DataTable`:

```cs
// read the schema into DataTable
public static void ReadSchema(DataTable dt,string schema)
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    ReadXMLToMemoryStream(schema, stream);
    dt.ReadXmlSchema(stream);
}

// read the data into DataTable
public static void ReadData(DataTable dt,string xml)
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    ReadXMLToMemoryStream(xml,stream);
    dt.ReadXml(stream);
}

// read xml string into MemoryStream
private static void ReadXMLToMemoryStream(string xml, MemoryStream stream)
{
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml.Trim());
    doc.Save(stream);
    stream.Position = 0;
}
```

To fix the issue, we need parse the related json properties (I'm using `Newtonsoft.Json`) :

```cs
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strReturnedFromWebApi);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
using(var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(ms))){
    var json = JToken.Load(reader);
    var version= json.SelectToken("$.['DataTable.RemotingVersion']");
    var schema = (string)json.SelectToken("$.XmlSchema");    // the schema part
    var data = (string)json.SelectToken("$.XmlDiffGram");    // the data part

    System.Data.DataTable dt =  new System.Data.DataTable();
    ReadSchema(dt,schema);       // read schema
    ReadData(dt,data);           // read data
}
```